# How to calculate the probability of getting at least one of each rank from a custom deck of cards?

Tags: probability

Custom deck of 60 cards. 
Ranks are 1,5,10,25 
and number of each rank is 20,16,12,12

Draw 5 cards without replacement.

How to calculate the probability of getting at least one of each rank from this custom deck of cards?

Using brute force and adding all the ways for each 5 card combination
I get 1290240/5461512.
(close to simulation value but could be wrong)

I think inclusion-exclusion would be easier
if I knew how to continue with it.

If there were just 15 of each rank
I just use Wolfram Alpha

$$C(60,5)^{-1} \big( \sum_{k=0}^3(-1)^k \cdot C(4,k) \cdot C(15(4-k),5) \big),$$

returns $\frac{16875}{65018}$ ($\frac{1417500}{5461512}$)

This is easy to simulate
but hope it is also easy to calculate.

If the example deck is too difficult
then a deck of

20-1s and 5s

and

10-10s and 25s
would be the easier question.

IF this has been answered before using items other than cards

I can 'deal with that' if shown a link to it.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get at least one from each of the $4$ ranks, when choosing $5$ cards, is to get exactly $1$ from each rank and $2$ from another. Now, the number of choices of $4$ distinct ranks are:

$$20 \cdot 16 \cdot 12 \cdot 12 = 46080$$

Now, a choice of $5$ cards with one repeated is a choice of $4$ distinct cards and then a choice of another card from one of the ranks. The number of these scenarios are:

$$46080\cdot (19 + 15 + 11 + 11) = 2580480$$

However, since each of these can always be made in $2$ ways, because $2$ cards are chosen from one of the ranks, we need to divide by $2$ to get our total number of desirable outcomes which is:

$$\frac{2580480}{2} = 1290240$$

The total number of choices are:

$$60 \choose 5$$

So the probability is:

$$\frac{1290240}{60 \choose 5} \approx 0.2362$$